# How to put custom user control on page layout

Tags: page-layout, publishing-page, user-controls

How can I add a custom user control to a page layout?

I have some custom user control developed. I want to place it in a custom page layout. So it will be in every page instance of that layout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First create your User Control and publish is to SharePoint.
Then you register a tag for your control

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="MyControls" 
    Namespace="KM.MyControls.MyControl" 
    Assembly="KM.MyControls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<Your token>" %>
```

Then you can reference your User Control

```
<MyControls:MyUserControl runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you put the user control into a subdirectory of {SharePointRoot}/Templates/ControlTemplates

Put a `Register` element at the top of you page-layout

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="MyOwnPrefix" TagName="MyUserControl" Src="~/_controltemplates/MyProjectName/UserControl.ascx" %>
```

and the refer to it where you need it like:

```
<MyOwnPrefix:MyUserControl runat="server" id="userControl" />
```

Comment: thank you, how should i deploy user control via solution? should i deploy it via module in a visual studio solution?

Comment: Create a Mapped folder to `{SharePointRoot}/Templates/ControlTemplates` create a subdirectory and put the UserControl there